# How can I implement JavaScript getUserMedia stub to send custom audio bytes

Tags: javascript, webrtc, getusermedia

I want to send custom audio bytes through WebRTC and that's why I need to write my custom getUserMedia method with my own MediaTrack. Here how it looks now:

```
     exports.navigator.getUserMedia = getUserMedia;


     function getUserMedia (constraints, successCallback) {
      console.log("window navigator: ",  exports.parent.navigator);
      console.log("call getUserMedia callback method callback = ", successCallback)
      console.log("createMediaStreamSource is: ",  exports.AudioContext.prototype.createMediaStreamSource);

      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                          postMessage('WKWebViewGetUserMediaShim_MediaStream_new', constraints, function (trackData) {
                                      var stream = new MediaStream()

                                      for (var i in trackData) {
                                      var data = trackData[i]
                                      var track = new MediaStreamTrack()

                                      track.id = data.id
                                      track.kind = data.kind
                                      track._meta = data.meta
                                      track._stream = stream
                                      console.log("track in promise = ", track);
                                      stream._tracks.push(track)
                                      exports.parent.navigator.tracks[track.kind] = exports.parent.navigator.tracks[track.kind] || {}
                                      exports.parent.navigator.tracks[track.kind][track.id] = track
                                      console.log("tracks in promise = ", tracks);
                                      }
                                     console.log("success callback = ", successCallback)
                                      resolve(stream)
                                      }, function(error){reject(error)})
                        });



    }

  getUserMedia._onmedia = function (kind, data) {

    var tracksByKind = exports.parent.navigator.tracks[kind]
    if (kind === 'audio') {
      data = new Float32Array(base64ToData(data))
    } else if (kind === 'video') {
      data = data
    }
//    console.log("onmedia tracks ", exports.parent.navigator.tracks);
    for (var i in tracksByKind) {
      var track = tracksByKind[i]
//      console.log("data came with data ", data);
//      console.log("track = : ", track);


      track._ondataavailable && track._ondataavailable(data)
    }
}
```

_onmedia method is where I get my custom bytes, and getUserMedia I'm trying to stub. But I do not know how to correctly set stream of custom bytes to MediaStreamTrack class.

Comment: The premise is completely false. To send  custom audio bytes use the Web Audio API and its [MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode)

Comment: How can I create it from scratch and put there bytes stream continuously?

Answer (score 1):

To generate audio from a web browser, use the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API).
Various methods will allow you to generate synthetic sounds.

If you wish to control every samples, you can use a ScriptProcessorNode and feed its [AudioProcessEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScriptProcessorNode/onaudioprocess)'s `outputBuffer`.

Web Audio API even has a MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode object that allows to output this generated audio inside a MediaStream object:

```js
btn.onclick = start;

function start() {

  const ctx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext);

  const processor = ctx.createScriptProcessor(256,1,1);
  processor.onaudioprocess = makeSomeNoise;
  
  const streamNode = ctx.createMediaStreamDestination();
  processor.connect(streamNode);
  const mediaStream = streamNode.stream;

  // for demo output to a MediaElement
  aud.srcObject = mediaStream;
  aud.volume = 0.5;
  aud.play();

}


function makeSomeNoise(evt) {

  const output = evt.outputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
  // loop through the 4096 samples
  for (let sample = 0; sample < output.length; sample++) {
    // noise
    output[sample] = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 0.5;         
  }
  
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">start</button>
<audio id="aud" controls></audio>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can I, in the same way, add some video to MediaStream?

Comment: Sure you can do `mediaStream.addTrack(videoTrack)`. If you mean to also generate the bytes from `videoTrack`, then do this from a canvas stream.

Comment: I have bytes from an external source, but how can I add these bytes to videoTrack?

Comment: What are these bytes supposed to represent?

Comment: It comes from native IOS app into the webview in base64 format and I want to add it to existing videoTrack continuesly.